# Sometimes Appium studio is not supported to launch IOS device

Tags: appium-ios

1) When click on the open device in appium studio to launch ios app, i got an error. Even when i am doing manually also, i experienced below same issue.

> Error Domain-XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=13 "Error
>   kAXErrorInvalidUIelement copying attributes 1102"
>   UseInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error kAXErrorInvalidElement copying
>   attributes 1102}

Note- I experienced above issue only IOS version- 12.2

2) When i execute IOS automation scripts, Sometimes it shows " Device disable". But, Earlier it works fine.

Please tell a solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please try it on their latest version 12.4. iOS 12.2 works for me in Appium studio v12.4.

Comment: Thank you Keerthana. I'll try

Comment: I have the same issue in V12.4  .... Could anyone please give a solution ? Appium stuido version - 12.1.80